# I want to read a file from stdin and read each line into a string and only use getchar

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int mygetchar();

int main(){
    mygetchar();
}

int mygetchar(){
    int c, i = 0;
    char line[1000];
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'){
        line[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", line);
    printf("%lu\n", strlen(line));
    return 0;
}
```

please see the picture of my code, my code can only come out with one string and one line of a file, but I want store each line of the file as a string and count their length and I can't use fgets, I can only use the getchar function, please help, thanks a lot.

Comment: first and foremost you need to create a file pointer and then use fopen()

Comment: Post the code instead of linking an image to it

Comment: @Mitchel0022: Why would that be necessary if OP just wants to read from `stdin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code basically handles characters until it reaches end of line or end of file, you can simply put *another* loop around it to do each line.

That would go something like:

```
int c = '\n'; // force entry into loop
while (c != EOF) {
    int i = 0;
    char line[1000];
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        line[i] = c; // should really check for buffer overflow here.
        i++;
    }
    line[i] = '\0'; // and here.
    printf ("%s\n", line);
    printf ("%lu\n", strlen (line));
}
```

Alternatively, you could just process all characters one by one, doing special handling for end of line (again, you should avoid buffer overflow, and you should probably move the common code into a function):

```
int c, i = 0;
char line[1000];
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    // Newline is special, print and reset.

    if (c == '\n') {
        line[i] = '\0';
        printf ("%s\n", line);
        printf ("%lu\n", strlen (line));
        i = 0;
    } else {
        line[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
}
// If data at end without newline.

if (i != 0) {
    line[i] = '\0';
    printf ("%s\n", line);
    printf ("%lu\n", strlen (line));
}
```

Comment: Instead of `int c = '\n'; // force entry into loop`, I would perhaps argue that a `do {} while()` loop would be nicer.

Comment: @HuYunfei: If you found the answer helpful, you may want to not only accept it, but also upvote it. It's the common etiquette unless you have reason not to.

Comment: Definitely do that